# Folder refuses to be deleted

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I created a subfolder in `/mnt` to have a mountpoint for something I needed briefly.

The device has been unmounted, so therefor I don't need that subfolder of `/mnt` anymore. But that subfolder refuses to be deleted.

I have tried `sudo rm -rfv foldername` several times.

Every time I get that the folder is successfully deleted, which in itself is ironic, because obviously you cannot delete the same thing several times.

I have also flushed `.bash_history` in case something is just cached. Even though the terminal outputs that the folder has been deleted successfully when doing ls to check it is still there.

I have both rebooted and completely shutdown the machine and booted it again; and checked with `ls`, still there.

Checked my `/var/log/syslog`. Nothing.

Comment: Are you using the full path?

Comment: I would guess sometimes is actively creating that folder as soon as you delete it

Comment: `-f` implies "ignore nonexistent files". Even if you are in a wrong directory or misspell `foldername`, `rm -rfv foldername` may return success after doing nothing. Do you get output from `-v` stating that `foldername` has just been removed?

Comment: Yes I have come to the conclusion that something is recreating the folder over and over again. I will reinstall the server anyhow. Lots of other things that I am not happy with about the setup. So then it will not be a problem. Thanks for the input anyhow.

Comment: Check `ls -i /mnt` before and after `rm`. If `foldername` gets a different inode number then you will know `rm` worked and something created the directory anew.